# fatal error: GoSdk/GoSdk.h: No such file or directory #include <GoSdk/GoSdk.h>

Tags: c, gcc

I have installed the `gcc` in window 10 and trying to compile the `ReceiveSurface.c` by running the `gcc ReceiveSurface.c`, but I keep getting error

```
fatal error: GoSdk/GoSdk.h: No such file or directory  
#include <GoSdk/GoSdk.h>
```

The file is actually a library downloaded from internet which the folder structure is very complex and interdependent.

ReceiveSurface.c:

```
#include <GoSdk/GoSdk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

* * * --- code --- * * *
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
- GO_SDK
  - Gocator
    - GoSdk
      - GoSdk
        - GoSdk.h             <--- header file that is missing
        - other .h files
  - Samples
    - ReceiveSurface
      - src
        - ReceiveSurface.c    <--- file that I want to compile
```

After hours of research and testing, such as including `-I` prefix, putting the `GoSdk.h` inside the `include` folder, changing include to relative path `#include "../../../../Gocator/GoSdk/GoSdk/GoSdk.h"`.

However, the issue remained. I am a beginner in C programming, and have absolutely no idea what is happening in the code, has anybody got an idea what is going on?

Comment: I suggest you use -I and your original include path.  In this case -I$path_to_first_GoSdk (.../GO_SDK/Gocator/GoSdk where you will need to add the ...)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest including the "GoSdk.dll" and "kApi.dll" files in the target folder where the executable is set to compile. Otherwise, the examples on the SDK don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to C programming and don't want to deal with these sort of issues, I definitely recommend using Visual Studio for working with samples in the Gocator SDK. The SDK includes Visual Studio "solution" files (.sln) that include all the settings necessary to compile the samples with a single button click.

[Include configuration in Visual Studio sample solution file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF7LR.png)